# ActionListener отдельно от класса

Tags: swing, java, graphics

Читаю `Swing`: руководство для начинающих. В начале `listener` "запхнут" в сам класс. Как организовать `listener` в отдельный класс?
Пример:

```
class ButtonDemo implements ActionListener{

public JLabel jlab;
ButtonDemo(){
    JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Frame!");
    jfrm.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    jfrm.setSize(535, 320);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton Button1=new JButton("+");
    JButton Button2=new JButton("Button2");
    Button1.addActionListener(this);
    Button2.addActionListener(this);
    Button1.setBounds(1, 1, 50, 50);
        Button2.setBounds(78, 90, 50, 50);
    jlab=new JLabel("LABEL!!!");
    jfrm.add(jlab);
    jfrm.add(Button1);
    jfrm.add(Button2);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")){
            jlab.setText("Pres 1");
            }
        else{
            jlab.setText("Pres 2");
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new ButtonDemo();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

P.S. Сам знаю, что не очень умный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо задекларировать класс типа:

```
class ButtonDemoActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("+")){
            jlab.setText("Press 1");
            }
        else{
            jlab.setText("Press 2");
            }
        }
}
```

и привязать его экземпляр к кнопке через:

```
Button button1=new Button();
button1.addActionListener(new ButtonDemoActionListener());
```

Comment: Для каждой кнопки?

Comment: @BubbleGum это уже на ваш выбор. Можете для каждой кнопки свой слушатель, а можете на все кнопки один и тот же.

Comment: А как, таким образом, сделать один слушатель на все кнопки?

Comment: Мозги включаем...

Comment: один слушатель у вас уже есть. Если хотите повесить его больше, чем на одну кнопку, то к примеру

button1.addActionListener(new ButtonDemoActionListener());
button2.addActionListener(new ButtonDemoActionListener());
button3.addActionListener(new ButtonDemoActionListener());

или

ButtonDemoActionListener l = new ButtonDemoActionListener();
button1.addActionListener(l);
button2.addActionListener(l);
button3.addActionListener(l);